# Error in declaring data in rstan for graded response model

Tags: r, stan, rstan

I am trying to use Stan, specifically through [`rstan`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rstan), to fit a [graded response model](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4757-2691-6_5). Luo and Jiao (2018), available [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6096466/), provide Stan code for doing so. Here is their code, edited only to include more white space:

```c
data{
    int<lower=2, upper=4> K; //number of categories
    int <lower=0> n_student;
    int <lower=0> n_item;
    int<lower=1,upper=K> Y[n_student,n_item];
}

parameters {
    vector[n_student] theta;
    real<lower=0> alpha [n_item];
    ordered[K-1] kappa[n_item]; //category difficulty
    real mu_kappa; //mean of the prior distribution of category difficulty
    real<lower=0> sigma_kappa; //sd of the prior distribution of category difficulty
}

model{
    alpha ~ cauchy(0,5);
    theta ~ normal(0,1);
    for (i in 1: n_item){
        for (k in 1:(K-1)){
            kappa[i,k] ~ normal(mu_kappa,sigma_kappa);
    }}
    mu_kappa ~ normal(0,5);
    sigma_kappa ~ cauchy(0,5);
    for (i in 1:n_student){
        for (j in 1:n_item){
            Y[i,j] ~ ordered_logistic(theta[i]*alpha[j],kappa[j]);
    }}
}

generated quantities {
    vector[n_item] log_lik[n_student];
    for (i in 1: n_student){
        for (j in 1: n_item){
            log_lik[i, j] = ordered_logistic_log (Y[i, j],theta[i]*alpha[j],kappa[j]);
    }}
}
```

However, when I try to use this code, the parser throws an error. Here is the R code to reproduce the error:

```r
library("rstan")

n <- 100
m <- 10
K <- 4
example_responses <- sample(x = 1:4, size = n * m, replace = TRUE)
example_responses <- matrix(example_responses, nrow = n, ncol = m)

example_dat <- list(K = K,
                    n_student = n,
                    n_item = m,
                    Y = example_responses)

fit <- stan(file = "~/grm.stan", data = example_dat)
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
SYNTAX ERROR, MESSAGE(S) FROM PARSER:
 error in 'modelf6471b3f018_grm' at line 2, column 21
  -------------------------------------------------
     2: 
     3: data {
     4:     int<lower=2, upper=4> K; // number of categories
                            ^
     5:     int<lower=0> n_student;                       
  -------------------------------------------------

PARSER EXPECTED: <one of the following:
  a variable declaration, beginning with type,
      (int, real, vector, row_vector, matrix, unit_vector,
       simplex, ordered, positive_ordered,
       corr_matrix, cov_matrix,
       cholesky_corr, cholesky_cov
  or '}' to close variable declarations>
Error in stanc(file = file, model_code = model_code, model_name = model_name,  : 
  failed to parse Stan model 'grm' due to the above error.
```

I've tried going through the code and the Stan manual to see what the issue is with the data declaration, but I can't find a problem with it. The declaration appears to be very similar to a declaration example in the [Stan Language Reference](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_23/reference-manual/overview-of-data-types.html):

```c
int<lower = 1> N;
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Your code has non-standard characters in some of the white space, including right after K;

Comment: @ssp3nc3r Interesting... I will try to check this out. Do you know a good way to programmatically detect non-standard characters that may be problematic?

Comment: I saw them highlighted as soon as I opened it in RStudio.

Comment: @ssp3nc3r I just manually replaced all the whitespace-type characters and it worked like a charm! Happy to accept if you add as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has non-standard characters in some of the white space, including right after K;